# How to loop or iterate through resultset or recordset by column in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a result set like -

```
ID, Name, Address
1,John, Japan
2,Sarah, UK
3,Jeremy, USA
```

I want to be able to select any column out of the above in the result set/record set and then iterate over that column's rows. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding an extension method to `SqlDataReader` to read all values from a given column, like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> ReadColumn<T>(this SqlDataReader rdr, int index) {
    while (rdr.Read()) {
        yield return (T)rdr.GetValue(index);
    }
}
```

With this method in place, you should be able to read a single column from your query like this:

```
var i = 1;
foreach (string name in cmd.ExecuteReader().ReadColumn<string>(1)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name {0} = {1}", i++, name);
}
```

Comment: Good to know. But, is there a simple way to also do it without extension methods ?

Comment: @blasto Not as far as I know. We use an extension method in production code at our company, and it works fine.

Comment: Easier approach - DataTable dt = some data table; 
DataColumn col = dt.Columns["ColumnYouWant"]; Iterate over each row using the example at http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11133/ssis-reading-object-variable-in-script-task.aspx

Comment: @blasto The problem with `DataDatble` is that it loads in memory more data than it is necessary. If this is fine with you, the `DataTable` approach may indeed be easier to implement.

Comment: What more does it load besides the resulting rows of data and names of columns ?

Comment: @blasto My understanding is that `DataTable` loads all the columns, not just the one column that you want.

Comment: Thanks.Then, maybe I can load only one column into DataTable and use it ? Would that be a better approach ?

Comment: @blasto In terms of writing new code, the approach based on the `DataTable` is indeed better, because it does not require new code at all. On the other hand, `ReadColumn<T>` function is so lightweight that it could be maintained by someone who is not familiar with the `DataTable` class at all. In general, I don't think there's an approach that's universally "better" for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an object (e.g. Person) with tree properties: ID, Name and Address

You can then create a list containing objects of that type.

ex:

```
List<Person> persons; 

var names =  persons.Select(p => Name);
```

You can do the same for all three properties.

Comment: Actually, the result set comes from an SQL query. I want my C# code to be able to iterate over it by column. I was looking for an answer similar to the one at - http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11133/ssis-reading-object-variable-in-script-task.aspx

Comment: I just edited the question. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: The above will work if you're using Entity Framework or similar to query your database. It's not clear what you're using to query your DB

Comment: That should be an `IEnumerable<string>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)) ;).